# Why does my program crash after running this particular function?

Tags: c++, crash, runtime

Whenever I type the command to run this function in my program, it runs and then crashes saying:

"The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusal way."

Why does it do this?

```
void showInventory(player& obj) {
    std::cout << "\nINVENTORY:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << obj.getItem(i);
        i++;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t" << obj.getItem(i) << "\n";
    }
}

std::string getItem(int i) {
        return inventory[i];
    }
```

Comment: How is getItem() written? does it directly index an array? are you running out of bounds?

Comment: It might be something to do with the fact that `i` is incremented 3 times in every loop iteration.

Comment: You're adding a string (`char *`) and the return value of  `obj.getItem(i)`. You probably meant to use `<<` instead of `+`.

Comment: @AK4749 It indexes an array that contains the player's inventory. Could it be the fact that the inventory array is null at the moment of execution?

Comment: @Schnouki Oh, you're right! My Java programming class is interfering with my C++ programming! Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Changed the code, but it didn't fix the crash.

Comment: Give us getItem() code as well else it's more of a guesswork

Comment: How do you initialize inventory? does its size always remain 20?

Comment: @NGambit Yes, inventory has an array which size is 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
std::string toDo(player& obj) //BY KEATON
{
    std::string commands[5] =   // This is the valid list of commands.
    {"help", "inv"};

    std::string ans;
    std::cout << "\nWhat do you wish to do?\n>> ";
    std::cin >> ans;

    if(ans == commands[0]) {
        helpMenu();
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(ans == commands[1]) {
        showInventory(obj);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Needs to be:

```
std::string toDo(player& obj) //BY KEATON
{
    std::string commands[5] =   // This is the valid list of commands.
    {"help", "inv"};

    std::string ans;
    std::cout << "\nWhat do you wish to do?\n>> ";
    std::cin >> ans;

    if(ans == commands[0]) {
        helpMenu();
        return "";
    }
    else if(ans == commands[1]) {
        showInventory(obj);
        return "";          // Needs to be '""'
    }
}
```

Credit to Prototype Stark!

Answer (score 0):

When i = 19, you get the last item in the array after which i becomes 20 and there is another getItem which should cause out of bounds exception

Comment: If you run through though, that doesn't happen. The for loop will be called with `i=18` and then it will be 20 at the end of the loop. So `i` doesn't hit 19 when it evaluates in the `for`. I had the same thought...

Comment: I see what you are saying now, fixed it, but it still crashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    std::cout << obj.getItem(i);
```

This is not very correctly. Don't use magic numbers. Instead of 20 use int listSize = obj.ListSize()   (which will be implemented by you)

```
listSize = obj.ListSize();
    for(int i = 0; i <listSize ; i++) {
        std::cout << obj.getItem(i);
```

In this way you will be sure that you are not out of range.

Also if you want to print 2 items in one loop (I don't get the reason why) you cand do :

```
void showInventory(player& obj) {   // By Johnny :D
    std::cout << "\nINVENTORY:\n";
    int listSize = obj.ListSize()/2; //if you are sure that is odd number
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
        std::cout << obj.getItem(i);
        i++;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t" + obj.getItem(i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ListSize a C++ function I can use?

Comment: You should write a method similar with what Prototype Stark wrote.

Answer (score 0):

write a function :

```
class player{
public:
//--whatever it defines 
int ListSize()
{
   return (sizeof(inventory)/sizeof(inventory[0]));
}
};
```

Then use

```
void showInventory(player& obj) {   // By Johnny :D
    int length = obj.ListSize();
    std::cout << "\nINVENTORY:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        std::cout << obj.getItem(i);
        i++;
        std::cout << "\t\t\t" << obj.getItem(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use i < obj.ListSize(); this will lead to calling this function on every iteration of loop.

Comment: @Prototype Stark All of it? I have many header files that are involved with each other.

Comment: also do getItem() and showInventory() belong in the "player" class?

Comment: @PrototypeStark No, they do not.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Here is the pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/Ee8rHSMg

I put the code in the order that it runs in.

Comment: @PrototypeStark What did you do?

Comment: changed the iteration from 20 to length

Comment: @PrototypeStark It wasn't. So I did and it still crashes. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: if there is anyway I can look at your code. How about VNC session? Teamviewer?

Comment: @PrototypeStark I will pack the code into a zip and give it to you.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Here:

http://www.2shared.com/file/oqOEE3c3/Mikes_Adventure.html

To replicate the crash, type 'new adventure'. Then type 'inv' to see the inventory, followed by the crash.

Comment: Alright, spotted the bug. It was to do with the function :
std::string toDo(player& obj){ }. wherever it returns NULL, just add return ""; - You're done.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Why could it not return NULL?

Comment: because NULL is a pointer, and it expects to return an object of std::string from the stack. Since NULL is (void*)0, C++ couldn't catch the error at compile time. At run time, the stack got corrupted and after execution of the function toDo(), the program just bailed out.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Hopefully someday, I can read and fully understand that. That day is coming! Thanks for your help!